# Azure Connection String - Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object

Tags: c#, azure, console-application, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download azure blobs in a Windows Console Application. When I build and debug the application my azure connection string is throwing an exception. This string works fine in my other asp.net app.

The offending line is:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxx==;BlobEndpoint=https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxxxx.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xxxxx.file.core.windows.net/"].ConnectionString);
```

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace CPGetAdverts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxx==;BlobEndpoint=https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxxxx.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xxxxx.file.core.windows.net/"].ConnectionString);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("newadverts").ListBlobs();
            // Retrieve filenames from container List
            var urls = new List<string>();
            int fileName = 1;

            foreach (var blob in container)
            {
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"\home\pi\Pictures\" + fileName + ".jpg"))
                {
                    var blobReference = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blob.Uri);
                    blobReference.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
                    fileName++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Source=CPGetAdverts   StackTrace:
>          at CPGetAdverts.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Diarmaid\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CPGetAdverts\CPGetAdverts\Program.cs:line 24
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would expect ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""] to reference the name of the connection string, not the connection string itself.  The call to retrieve the connection string is unnecessary if are hard-coding it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679605/connecting-azure-blob-with-azure-website) for details.

Comment: Except this is a console application so should I put my connection string into app.config or packages.config?

Comment: app.config, packages.config is for nuget

Comment: You my friend are a genius. The cat is in the hat! (The images are in the local drive!!) :) Thankyou!!!!!!